# Squarefree counting function using zeta zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

So in Wolfram alpha there's this demonstration where the zeta zeros are used to calculate the function $\sum_{n\le x} \mu^2 (n)$  :(https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UsingZetaZerosToCountTheSquarefreeIntegers/)
It seems to be pretty accurate and work out nicely, and in the description the formula that is used to calculate it shows up. It is the sum of the residues you get when using perrons formula for $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ , when using a rectangle as a countour, which means that the other three integrals over the three sides of the square other than the one from perrons formula, vanish. I've tried seeing this myself, and it seems to be true, I might need to check a couple details back. 
Thing is though, this formula doesn't show up anywhere else at all, not on Wikipedia, I don't even see any article or book with it being mentioned, so am I doing poor search or does this mean it's not known whether the three other integrals vanish?

Comment: Have you tried using the functional equation to get an idea of the decrease of $|\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)|$ in the left half plane? I'm trying to make an argument like this and it seems like it's going to come down to examining how $|\Gamma(-2z)/\Gamma(-z)|$ decreases for large $\Re[z]>0.$ I have not looked at the two horizontal parts of the contour yet though.

Comment: Yes , the functional equation is something I used and it worked specifically nicely for the vertical part, for the horizontal parts, I think it can work as well but the work I did was kinda sloppy. For the vertical part, with the gamma function, I used Stirling's formula for the gamma function on complex numbers, which is valid for Re(z)>0 and it seems to work out well

Comment: Thing is I think I got $\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ tho, not what you got, with negative arguments

Comment: I’ll have to see where I went wrong. I might try proving a similar identity for the Mertens function to get a better grasp on this too; it seems like the simplest case of this type of formula.

Comment: Yeah the merten's function is easier, since you don't have any zeta on the numerator, and correction to my last comment I meant I got $\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(2z)}$.